ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : custom authentication handler and Angular HttpInterceptor [receive Status code =0 for 401 Unauthorized Response]
I have written a custom authentication handler in .NET Core. The custom handler works fine. If a user is unauthorized, it returns http 401 Unauthorized.
In the UI, I use an Angular HttpInspector to receive the unauthorized response sent from the API.
I faced two problems:

In the HttpInspector, I do not receive the status 401, the status code I receive is 0
For any authenticate user (status code 200 Ok), I do not receive any CORS problem. but for unauthorized response I am getting CORS problem (I also configured the Cors policy in the program.cs file in ASP.NET Core Web API):


Screenshot of CORS configuration in Program.cs:

Here is the code for custom authentication handler:
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
        string failReason;

        // Constructor to initialize base
        public CustomAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) :base(options,logger, encoder, clock)
        {
        }
    
        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            {
                failReason = "Himadri You failed";
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail(failReason);
            }
    
            string strAuthorization = Request.Headers["Authorization"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strAuthorization)) 
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorized");
            }
    
            try
            {
                var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                string token = strAuthorization.Substring("bearer".Length).Trim();
                var tokenS = handler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
                //var id = tokenS.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "nameid").Value;
    
                var claim = new List<Claim>
                                {
                                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "himadri")
                                };
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claim, Scheme.Name);
                var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);

                return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail(ex.Message);
            }
       }
    
       protected override Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
       {
            //Response.StatusCode = 401;
    
            if (failReason != null)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 401;
                Response.Headers.Append("access-control-expose-headers", "WWW-Authenticate");
                   
                Response.Headers.Append("WWW-Authenticate", failReason);
                Response.WriteAsync(failReason);
              
                Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = failReason;
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
}

If I call the API from Postman, it shows the status code and header perfectly:

But if call the API from my Angular application [in a HTTPInterceptor], then for unauthenticated user, I get status code = 0 and CORS problem occurs, but for authenticated user data is returned properly, status code = 200 and no CORS problem.
[Please refer to the 1st and 2nd screenshot]
Screenshot of HTTPInterecptor:

What am I missing here? Without receiving proper status code and header, how can I display proper message for unauthenticated/unauthorized users?
How can I receive proper status code and headers in Angular application from .NET Core custom authentication middleware?

status code 0 doesn't come from the server... it's basically angular's way of saying it doesn't know what happened.  (server probably didn't respond... probably because you've overridden HandleChallengeAsync, and you're not returning anything?  Not sure I understand this:  return Task.CompletedTask;  (also app.useCors should be called before app.useAuthentication... also be aware that you can't wildcard origins on requests with credentials)

I had a test in my side with your custom authenticationHandler, but I used a blazor WASM application as the client to test API, when I added a bearer token in the request header, it worked well, without the token, I can successfully get the 401 error and see the response header. I'm afraid your issue might relate to the React client. In API side, I could only see an issue that you might put app.UseCors(); before app.UseAuthentication(); because CORS middleware should be called before authentication middleware.

thanks @TinyWang. As per your suggestion i placed the app.UseCors(); before app.UseAuthentication(); . Now  a am receiving 401 status code for unauthorized response in angular UI. Thnaks for your Help. You saved me and my lot of time

Thank you for your confirmation! I also test in my side with app.UseCors() placed after authentication, and it also worked for my blazor wasm client. Maybe it also depends on client types. Anyway, I'm glad to see the issue resolved : )

Based on OP's confiramtion, putting app.UseCors(); before app.UseAuthentication(); can solved the issue, because CORS middleware should be called before authentication middleware. See middlware order here.
